# wrong partition UUID in fstab and partition showing as W95

Tags: ubuntu, partition, dual-boot, fstab, uuid

I have Win10 / Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot, and something messed up my partitions. I did try to resize the Win10 partition in order to enlarge my Ubuntu partition, but that didn't work so I resized back **and the Ubuntu OS worked fine after that**.

The Ubuntu OS started booting into emergency mode, after I commented out 2 lines in `/etc/fstab` it boots OK (without access to these 2 partitions) and the fstab file looks like:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=0c6086f3-8854-4a14-a4f2-d5836d1e63fa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=4e3c7655-e09c-40ff-ab56-7e9a2697d0ad /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#UUID=882b5e35-082f-4b8f-8fcf-5caef75083f4 none            swap    sw              0       0
# (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
#UUID=60d8bff6-4bbb-4b72-aa4b-6f89737ad238   /home        ext4    defaults       0       2
```

Currently, `/boot` is on `sda3` but `/` is on `sda5` and not `sda7` as written in the fstab (I don't know if it matters). I had to comment out the `swap` and `home` lines, which refer to UUIDs which are not present.

The output of `blkid` shows 2 partitions (`sda1` and `sda2`) which belong to the Win10 installation, and 2 partitions (`sda3` and `sda5`) which belong to Ubunto. But `sda4`, where my `/home` was on, is not showing. when I try `file -s /dev/sda4` I get

```
/dev/sda4: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x83, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 1, 39366656 sectors; partition 2 : ID=0x5, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 39366594, 31998015 sectors, extended partition table
```

and `fdisk -l /dev/sda` gives

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   3074047   3072000   1.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         3084480 244380779 241296300 115.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       244381696 248381439   3999744   1.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       248383487 488396799 240013313 114.5G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       248383488 287750143  39366656  18.8G 83 Linux
```

So for some reason this partition is shown as `W95`. 
Also, `fdisk -l /dev/sda4` shows

```
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=39366594): Invalid argument
Disk /dev/sda4: 1 KiB, 1024 bytes, 2 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device      Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda4p1             1 39366656 39366656 18.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4p2      39366594 71364608 31998015 15.3G  5 Extended
```

Any advice how to recover that lost `sda4` partition?
**EDIT** Is it safe to try and change the partition type using `cfdisk`?

**EDIT2**
maybe this helps to understand, from `cfdisk`. That `free space` device at the end shouldn't be there, that's the space where `/home` was.

```
    Device                Boot                     Start               End           Sectors           Size         Id Type
>>  /dev/sda1             *                         2048           3074047           3072000           1.5G          7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT        
    Free space                                   3074048           3084479             10432           5.1M
    /dev/sda2                                    3084480         244380779         241296300         115.1G          7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sda3                                  244381696         248381439           3999744           1.9G         83 Linux
    /dev/sda4                                  248383487         488396799         240013313         114.5G          f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
    ├─/dev/sda5                                248383488         287750143          39366656          18.8G         83 Linux
    └─Free space                               287752192         488396799         200644608          95.7G
```

**EDIT3**
Output of `blkid`:

````
/dev/sda3: UUID="4e3c7655-e09c-40ff-ab56-7e9a2697d0ad" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8f76ec72-03"
/dev/sda3: UUID="4e3c7655-e09c-40ff-ab56-7e9a2697d0ad" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8f76ec72-03"
/dev/sda4: PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="8f76ec72-04"
/dev/sda5: UUID="0c6086f3-8854-4a14-a4f2-d5836d1e63fa" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8f76ec72-05"```
````

Comment: I'll add it in the question. I have some important data on it so I prefer not to format it unless there's no other option

Comment: Not sure what you changed. And labels in fstab are what partitions were when installed, not necessarily after changes. And changes with Windows can create issues. Only use Windows tools to shrink NTFS and always have a backup of partition table with `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT_sda.txt`  The extended partition cannot have data, it is just a container for logical partitions. Note that sda4 starts at same sector as sda5. But you have unallocated space in the extended partition. Is that another logical partition with data? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2288988

Comment: The unallocated space has the lost /home partition which had its own logical partition. I am currently using a partition recovery tool from within windows, and it identified the 2 partitions on the unallocated space (there was also a swap partition there).

Comment: Btw, how can I restore a partition table that was saved using `sfdisk` you suggested?

Comment: More info on sfdisk. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1192598 See also `man sfdisk` Old versions did not support gpt, new versions now support gpt and text file structure is different. So be sure to use same version of sfdisk. Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition

Answer (score 1):

I post this as answer since it solved my problem:

1. The problem reason was (probably) resizing the Win10 partition from within Win10, that messed up the Linux partition table for some reason.
2. Using testdisk from Ubuntu live-cd, I recovered the lost partition
3. I had to edit `/etc/fstab` manually to set my home folder back to the lost partition.
4. I learned my lesson regarding the importance of backups :)